# Python Exe Obtain Logs

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I created an exe from a python file with pyinstaller and I wanted to save the logs send by the console when executing the python script directly (with format .py). So if there is any error in the code the user could see it in a txt with all the logs or something like this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When you execute a script from console you obtain some comments and in case of an error you could read which was the problem. With the executable when an error arise the application close inmediately. I want to save those logs.